# Como deixar formulário do CEP deslizando igual o site do ifood?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Este é o formulário do site que eu quero alterar: 
[artnaweb.com.br/pediragua](https://www.artnaweb.com.br/pediragua)

Deixar igual a este: 
[ifood.com.br](https://www.ifood.com.br/)

Eu não entendo Jquery. Eu tenho conhecimento apenas de HTML e CSS.
Obrigado!

Comment: Seria interessante você mostrar o que já tentou e postar seu código, da forma que esta a pergunta não vai se possível da uma resposta canônica.  Faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: Cara procure por funções Jquey

Comment: Legal, obrigado pela sugestão.. sou novo no site e este é o meu primeiro post. Mas da próxima vez, seguirei as orientações da "casa" rs. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Bira, se vc tem conhecimento de CSS3 pode criar a animação no CSS3 e usar o javascript apenas para incluir a classe da animação, mas não precisa nem usar Jquery se não conhecer, pode ser com Javascript puro mesmo.

Exemplo de código javascript que pode ser utilizado para adicionar uma classe em um algum elemento localizado pelo id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ani(){
        document.getElementById('img').className ='classname';
    }
</script>

Botão q ativa a função:
<input type="button"  name="" value="Teste"  onclick="ani()" />
```

Agora segue abaixo um exemplo funcional com animação correndo para o lado e desaparecendo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.desapareceesquerda, .aparecedireita, .apareceesquerda, .desaparecedireita {
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.desapareceesquerda { -webkit-animation-name: desapareceesquerdaAnimation; }

.aparecedireita { -webkit-animation-name: aparecedireitaAnimation; }

.apareceesquerda { -webkit-animation-name: apareceesquerdaAnimation; }

.desaparecedireita { -webkit-animation-name: desaparecedireitaAnimation; }


@keyframes desapareceesquerdaAnimation {
  from {
   margin-left:0;
   opacity:1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   z-index:2;
  }
      
  to {
    margin-left:-50%;
 opacity:0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 z-index:1;
  }
}


@keyframes aparecedireitaAnimation {
  from {

   opacity:0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   width:50%; left:50%;
   z-index:1;
  }
      
  to {

 opacity:1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 width:100%; left:0;
 z-index:2;
  }
}


@keyframes apareceesquerdaAnimation {
  from {
    margin-left:-50%;
 opacity:0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 z-index:1;  

  }
      
  to {
   margin-left:0;
   opacity:1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   z-index:2; 
  }
}


@keyframes desaparecedireitaAnimation {
  from {
 opacity:1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 width:100%; left:0;
 z-index:2;
  }
      
  to {
   opacity:0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   width:50%; left:50%;
   z-index:1;  
  }
}



#container { width:80%; margin:auto; position:relative;}

#divesquerda,#divdireita { float:left; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }

#divesquerda { background-color:#fda; z-index:2;  }

#divdireita { 
 background-color:#adf; width:50%;  /* div começa encolhida pela metade pra não criar barra de rolagem */
 left:50%; 
 z-index:1;
 
 opacity:0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */  
} 


</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function saiesquerdaentradireita(){
            document.getElementById('divesquerda').className ='desapareceesquerda';
   
   document.getElementById('divdireita').className ='aparecedireita';
        }
  
        function saidireitavoltaesquerda(){
            document.getElementById('divesquerda').className ='apareceesquerda';
   
   document.getElementById('divdireita').className ='desaparecedireita';
        }  
  </script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="divesquerda">
  <input type="button"  name="" value="&laquo; Trocar"  onclick="saiesquerdaentradireita()" /> <br>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKG89.jpg?s=328&g=1" width="308" height="308" />
 </div>

 <div id="divdireita">
  <input type="button"  name="" value="Voltar &raquo;"  onclick="saidireitavoltaesquerda()" /> <br>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1793996810886126/picture?type=large" width="308" height="308" />
 </div>

 <br clear="both">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Antonio, boa noite!
Obrigado por me ajudar... Eu não tenho conhecimento avançado em CSS... más com base no que vc colocou aqui, eu consegui fazer a animação do formulário desaparecer.... más como eu faço para aparecer outro formulário e ter a opção de voltar (igual o site do ifood) Mais uma vez obrigado, e desculpa se estou abusando.. rs

Comment: Você pode tentar pôr uma div invisível do lado da outra e fazer ela aparecendo. Pra fazer o voltar faz outra animação com outro nome fazendo o inverso. Vou criar um exemplo melhor aqui e edito minha resposta.

Comment: Pow show.. super agradeço se vc consegui criar o código de exemplo!

Comment: Editei o código do exemplo. Agora tem duas divs.

Comment: Show parceiro top! consegui deu tudo certo!
Muitíssimo obrigado... se tiver alguma coisa que eu possa fazer como retribuição aqui pelo site, só falar.. ajudou muito! =D
Parabéns!!!

Comment: Que bom! Fico feliz! Grande abraço! :)